# How to select first result from pandas .sort_values()

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to select the first result from an excel sheet result in a specific column for .sort_values()

`import pandas as pd`

`df = pd.read_excel (r'/PATH/filename.xlsx')`

```
dff = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Unnamed: 4'])
sbl = dff.sort_values('Unnamed: 4')
print sbl.head(n=4)

#Unnamed: 4
27      18465
29      18532
28      18550    
30      18594
```

How do I take the first result `27 18465` and only use `18465`
for mathematical equations?

Comment: try `df['#Unnamed:4'].iloc[0]` or `df['#Unnamed: 4'].values[0]` or `df['#Unnamed: 4'].tolist()[0]`

Comment: For accessing a single entry, `df.at` and `df.iat` are the preferred solution https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html

Comment: @alec_djinn Thank you for the link, it solved my issue.

Comment: @Datanovice your comment was also useful to me, will use for future use. Thank you

Comment: How do I select @alec_djinn 's comment as a the solution? 

Comment: @Livermore.Silk you can't select comments as a solution for your question. I have added it as an answer. Usually, for simple questions like the one you posted, a comment is enough to help the OPs solving their problems.

Answer (score 1):

For accessing a single entry, `df.at` and `df.iat` are the preferred solution.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html